# Передать массив из php в javascript через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, веб-программирование

Есть файл result.php, в котором берутся два значения из БД и записываются в массив. Нужно передать этот массив в файл result.js для дальнейшей работы с ним. Пока вместо желаемого мне результата, на конечную страницу (index.php, на которой вначале я прописал `<?php include 'result.php'; ?>`) выводится сам массив в формате json, а содержимое страницы пропадает. Пробовал делать и через POST, и через GET в Ajax'е, результат одинаковый. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

result.php:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "DB_USERNAME";
    $dbpassword = "DB_PASS";
    $databasename = "DB_NAME";

    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $databasename);
    
    $query = "SELECT Name, Surname FROM people ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $name = $row['Name'];
    $surname = $row['Surname'];
    $data = ["name" => $name, "surname" => $surname];

    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;

    mysqli_close($db);

    exit();
?>
```

В файле result.js получаю следующим образом:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'result.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success(data){
        var res = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: и зачем вы делаете `include result.php` в индексе?

Comment: Можете показать результат аякс запроса?

Comment: @teran действительно, на автомате поставил, убрал, теперь все работает, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

укажите в Ajax запросе type:'GET'. При при работе с JSON я бы держался метода GET.
Подробнее можете ознакомиться [тут](https://msiter.ru/tutorials/jquery/jquery_ajax/get_post#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%2D%20GET%20%D0%B8%20POST.&text=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%20GET%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC,%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.).